# How can I look for this expression in the C# specification

Tags: c#

I know what the following expression does; what I want to know is how is it called in the C# specification?

```
var a= new  int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
a[^1];
```

Answer: `3`

Comment: Index from end. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges

Comment: Indices and ranges introduced in c# 8 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges